# Running an Excel Macro through Python without being able to change Trust Center Settings

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I'm trying to automate a process, a portion of which involves running an Excel based macro from the source file and saving it.

Due to the prevailing security policy in my company, all of Excel's Trust Center Settings have been grayed out which means the default Macro settings are "Disable all Macros with Notifications"

Below is the excerpt of the code I'm trying to run.

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(my_sheet) 
xl.Application.Run(my_sheet + '!Module1.Macro1')
```

Where my_sheet contains the location of excel sheet e.g. `'C:\Users\Desktop\MyFile.xlsm'`

Now this returns me with the following error

```
The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

My guess is that this is because Macro settings are disabled in Trust Center policy. Is there a way we can bypass this through Python code and allow the macro to be executed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to bypass a user's security settings. If there were, what would be the point in having them?

Comment: Thanks. So there isn't any way we can run this Macro through Python?

Comment: Not if the security settings need to be changed, no.

Comment: *"Due to the prevailing security policy in my company"*: The companies policy is clear here! If you don't follow their rules and break security this is a clear breach of trust and a reason for dismissal. So if you don't want to find yourself out on the street I recommend to follow the companies rules and if you have issues with those rules ask the administrator or supervisor to change those rules or give you the rights you need.

Comment: You could probably replicate the macro’s tasks in Python … not ideal, but probably fits better within your company policy.